# Rails rspec - how to check model for validation that has ", if: :direct" clause

Tags: ruby, validation, rspec, shoulda, matcher

I have this model code:

```
validates_presence_of :setting_id  
validates_presence_of :user_id  
validates_presence_of :topic_id, if: :direct?
```

I have these rspec tests:

```
it { should validate_presence_of :setting_id }
it { should validate_presence_of :user_id }
it { should validate_presence_of(:topic_id).if(:direct?) }
```

The first 2 tests work ok.
The last one gives an error of:
`undefined method 'if' for #<Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel::ValidatePresenceOfMatcher:0x007fda6a5c6268>`

How can I add a similar tests for code fragment for the last presence of validation for `(:topic_id).if(:direct?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source code for shoulda-matchers, it looks like the `:if` condition is not supported. You will need to test this manually with stubbed values for the `direct?` method.